# My laptop's screen is flickering

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers

Last week i see a Windows Update. As soon as i click "restart now" for update, top side of my screen started flickering.

I removed both Intel HD Graphics and Nvidia drivers, then installed them again.

I've tried to do it in Security Mode, it flickered randomly also in security mode.
It also happens in BIOS, which is weird. Also i tried to do clean install with USB, it was flickering again. I am 100% sure that i did not drop my laptop or damaged it's screen. And this started when i did Windows Update. While it started flickering, only way for get rid of this situation is getting into Sleep Mode and opening it again.

I disabled "automatically download manufacturers' apps and custom icons that are available for your devices" option in Device installation settings and removed my drivers. It stopped flickering for a while. As soon as this problem stopped, i also tried "reset Windows" option in troubleshooting settings. So i did a clean setup and it is flickering again.

To sum up, nothing solved my problem. I don't think it is a hardware problem but it was flickering also in BIOS so i am afraid.

Is this problem caused because some damage or it's totally driver problem?

Comment: Attach an external display. It the external display does not flicker, then you have a hardware problem. Take it to a local shop.

Comment: I was not able to attach it to an external display but when my friend connect to my laptop with Teamviewer, there was no flickering for his screen. Also i took a screen record while flickering, but it wasn't captured by screen recorder. That means it is hardware problem? @John

Comment: Yes. That means a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @John

Comment: This is a difficult situation to explain but just because a car broke down the moment it entered a city doesn't mean that the city broke the car.

Comment: ↑ also known as [post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) ;))

Comment: If it flickers in BIOS, then it's hardware, possibly a fluorescent back-light slowly going bad (fairly easy to replace), or the display driver (more expensive).

Comment: A quick update - i bring my laptop to Asus service, and they confirmed some monitor issue. Thanks all, i should've brought it before but anyways, it'll be fixed. @John